# Using images in pop-up in leaflet that remain within the HTML

Tags: r, leaflet, markdown

I am creating an HTML file with leaflet and R for a proyect. The Idea is to add multiple markers in a map, and be able to click them and see a description as well as a picture. Here's an example code.

```
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(imager))
coor<-c("11","-55","EG",
"12","-54","EG2")
df<-matrix(coor,ncol=3,byrow = TRUE)
df<-data.frame(lon=as.numeric(df[,1]),lat=as.numeric(df[,2]),Iden=df[,3])
descr<-c("Description written in popup.
         \n <img src=\"/A:/Path/FIle/Pics/EG.jpg\">",
"description 2 \n <img src=\"/A:/Path/FIle/Pics/EG_2.jpg\">")
df<-cbind.data.frame(df,descr)
colnames(df)[4]<-descr
coordinates(df) <- ~lat+lon
leaflet(df) %>% addMarkers(popup = ~descr,label = ~Iden) %>% addTiles()
```

The picture is shown properly if I open the file in my PC, however, when using the file in another device, the image is not there, because the  `img src` is indicating a file location. What I want is to be able to export a single HTML file that contains the images in each pop-up, that can be oppened in any device.
How can I do this ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the image into a URL using base64 (e.g see this [web service](https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/))

Example Image: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196

Example HTML tag:

```
<img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" />
```